# How to write array for json encode to look like this

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get a specific json response, but one array in the response is being passed as an object.

```
"countries":{"TW":8,"JP":5,"AU":6,"MX":12,"CL":4,"HK":2,"US":14,"AR":4,"ES":1,"BR":1,"MY":9,"IT":12,"DE":1,"GB":1,"PE":6,"TR":1,"KR":3,"IE":1,"CA":2,"FR":1,"VE":2,"IL":1,"PT":1,"NL":1,"PL":1}
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
"countries":[["Brazil", 40.5],["US", 30],["Canada", 19.5], ["England", 10]]
```

How do I build that array in PHP for the json_encode response looks like that?

Now I have:

```
$countries['US']=14;
$countries['CL']=4;
....
```

Then I add that array ($countries) to the $data array, which is the one json encoded

```
$data['countries'] = $countries;
```

Which gives the result I posted first. But I need that in that in the second format.

Anyone knows what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$countries = Array();
$countries[] = Array('Brazil', 40.5);
 ...
```

Comment: So an array for each country then?

Comment: An array for each array in the JSON.